# new tags in HTML purifier

Tags: php, xhtml, html-parsing, htmlpurifier

I get warnings like this for the `<strike>`, `<del>` and `<datetime>` tags:

> Warning: Element 'strike' is not
>   supported (for information on
>   implementing this, see the support
>   forums) in ...
>
> Attribute 'datetime' in element 'del'
>   not supported (for information on
>   implementing this, see the support
>   forums)

So how do I implement them?

Or where exactly do I have to look in their forums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html

Comment: yeah, I found that too, in about 90 seconds of looking, and I've never touched HTML Purifier before.

Comment: that's really hard :( anyway I changed the doc type to xhtml transitional and the strike warning went away :D

Comment: Yeah, you have to essentially teach HTML Purifier precisely what the element is supposed to look like.